# Excel text string shouldn't paste as date

Tags: excel, csv, format, cell

I want to copy a selection of cells from one workbook to another, the latter of which is a csv file. Both files already exist, and I use a script to delete the contents of the csv file before pasting in the new values.

One of the columns is for user-selected passwords, and sometimes users use a string that looks like a date as their password. Even though the originating file correctly displays the text as "august10" the csv file formats it as 10-Aug. I've tried everything I can think of and don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here's the script I'm using:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "CSVfile.csv" _
        , Origin:=xlWindows
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Windows("OriginalFile.xls").Activate
    Sheets("Manipulate").Select
    Range("Extract").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("CSVFile.csv").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

look up something like NumberFormat vba

Comment: I have done that, which is where I got Selection.NumberFormat = "@"  I have also moved that command to appear underneath Selection.ClearContents. It didn't work, and that's why I'm scratching my head.